# Why do Generic types not propagate to all class methods?

Tags: java, generics

Other than adding an annotation, is there a way to properly resolve the warning about casting `Boolean` to `K` in the return statement? I am instantiating `Foo<Boolean, Integer>`, so `K` *is* an `Integer` when instance method `foo()` is executed, correct?

```
public class Foo<K, V> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Foo<Boolean, Integer>()).foo();
    }

    public K foo() {
        return (K) Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: So, as was suggested, I ended up refactoring the code and everything's splendid now.

Comment: What if you provided a type argument of `String`? How would `(String) Boolean` work?

Comment: What wrong with `ClassCastException` at runtime??

Comment: It breaks every good practice programming concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By casting `Boolean.FALSE` to `K`, you're essentially saying that `K` should always be `Boolean` (or your code would throw an exception). Then why not change all occurrences of `K` to `Boolean`, and remove the generic type parameter from the class definition?

```
public class Foo<V>
{
    public Boolean foo()
    {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

If you really intend to have `Foo<K, V>` then you must only include methods that work with any `K` (and any `V`) in the class. So, then I suggest you remove `foo()` and move it somewhere else, where it is known that a particular instance of `Foo<K, V>` always has `Boolean` for `K`.

Comment: you've ppointed me in the right direction - i ended up creating a kind of callback that's called from the "generic" class, and that callback manipulates the booleans and returns them back to "generic" class.